# How to fix 'POSTAGE' not found error in market basket analysis basket_sets.drop

Tags: python, dataset

I am using a large dataset to do market basket analysis, but I am not getting any  results. How do I get past the error of:

> 'POSTAGE' not found in axis

I have commented out the code:

```
basket_sets.drop('POSTAGE', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

to see if it works without it, but I get no results.

```
def encode_units(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if x >= 1:
        return 1

basket_sets = basket.applymap(encode_units)
basket_sets.drop('POSTAGE', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

I expect the output withantecedents, confidence etc

Answer (score 0):

See here:
[Python MBA](https://pivotbillions.com/maximizing-sales-with-market-basket-analysis/)
[MBA](https://towardsdatascience.com/mba-for-breakfast-4c18164ef82b)

Remove this line from your code:

```
basket_sets.drop('POSTAGE', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

and script run to next line :

```
frequent_itemsets = apriori(basket, min_support=0.05, use_colnames=True)
```